# Cakephp change defaultLocale on runtime

Tags: cakephp, internationalization

Have a multilanguage app and i want the admin to be able to specify the "default website built language".
For this ive created a table with language entries that the admin can choose from. Users can then choose the language they want the app in, which ive done with I18n::setLocale(...) in AppController.
The problem is that if the main language the admin sets the site to, does not match config/app.php App.defaultLocale, the app will try to save content in the translation table instead of the main table.

Ive tried using ini_set('intl.default_locale',..) in the boostrap.php, as well as Configure::write('App.defaultLocale',..); and none of them seem to work, however if I alter config/app.php to the desired language specified by the admin the app behaves as expected.

My goal is to specify at runtime the app language so that the behavior matches config/app.php without the need of changing the app.php config file.

Answer (score 0):

We do it this way in AppController:

```
$locale = ... get locale from URL, session, cookie, database etc.
I18n::setLocale($locale);
CakeTime::setDefaultLocale($locale);
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but this does not work on the scenario ive described above. This is correct procedure to save content into a diferent language or render the app to diff language, however what im trying to achieve is telling cake that the "language the website was built" is diferent from specified in app.config

Comment: "The problem is that if the main language the admin sets the site to, does not match config/app.php App.defaultLocale, the app will try to save content in the translation table instead of the main table." - I think the problem here is that the default translation is saved to the main table. We never use the main table for the default translation. All our translations are saved to i18n table including the default one.